# Firefox refuse to use GPU hardware acceleration with Nvidia GPU. How to fix?

Tags: nvidia, firefox, video, gpu

Trying to turn on GPU acceleration in Firefox 115 snap.

Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

NVIDIA Corporation GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 6GB]

NVIDIA Driver Version: 535.54.03

```
layers.acceleration.force-enabled = true

layers.offmainthreadcomposition.enabled = true (this key was missing, created it)
```

I restarted Firefox, rebooted system.
To check if it works I started `nvidia-smi dmon`, played youtube and local `h264.mp4` with Firefox to see if there is anything other than 0 in `dec` column of terminal output. When I play a video with VLC, it shows some % of decoding load with GPU, but Firefox refuse to use GPU. Any ideas how to fix it? Thank you!

UPDATE

Thanks to Raffa's answer, I've changed some other settings, here they are:

```
gfx.webrender.all false -> true
dom.webgpu.enabled false -> true
layers.gpu-process.enabled false -> true
layers.mlgpu.enabled add
media.gpu-process-decoder false -> true
media.ffmpeg.vaapi.enabled true (no change)
```

No success. Also tried the same tests with Chromium, no success.
In Firefox `about:support` I have found a lot of failures, here are some of them:

WebGPU adapter by default `"navigator.gpu.requestAdapter({})": { "not_supported": "WebGPU is not yet available in Release or Beta builds."`

GPU_PROCESS `Disabled by default = Enabled via layers.gpu-process.enabled = Blocked; error code FEATURE_FAILURE_DISABLED`

WEBRENDER_COMPOSITOR `Disabled by default = Cannot be enabled in release or beta    = Blocked; error code FEATURE_FAILURE_DISABLE_RELEASE_OR_BETA`

WEBGPU  `WebGPU cannot be enabled in release or beta = Blocked; error code WEBGPU_DISABLE_RELEASE_OR_BETA`

HARDWARE_VIDEO_DECODING `default = available ; user = force_enabled ; runtime = unavailable = Force disabled by gfxInfo = Blocked; error code FEATURE_FAILURE_VIDEO_DECODING_TEST_FAILED`

Now i wonder, maybe i should try some alpha build?

UPDATE 2

So I have tried Firefox Nightly which is early alpha build. And yes, some failure strings from `about:support` gone, for example this one:
**WebGPU adapter by default**      `"wgpuBackend": "Vulkan", "wgpuDevice": 7171, "wgpuDeviceType": "DiscreteGpu", "wgpuDriver": "NVIDIA", "wgpuDriverInfo": "535.54.03", "wgpuName": "NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 6GB", "wgpuVendor": 4318`

But still **HARDWARE_VIDEO_DECODING** says `Force disabled by gfxInfo ; FEATURE_FAILURE_VIDEO_DECODING_TEST_FAILED`

After changing setting `media.hardware-video-decoding.force-enabled = true` and restarting Firefox Nightly i see in terminal output `[GFX1-]: vaapitest: ERROR   [GFX1-]: vaapitest: VA-API test failed: failed to initialise VAAPI connection.`

So far what I found is that VA-API [can not work](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1765963) with proprietary Nvidia drivers that I need to encode video with GPU (NVENC). It seems I have to stop here, hope someone will find a solution.

Comment: Somewhat related and could help: https://askubuntu.com/a/1466268

Comment: Thank you very much, your link was quite useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, finally I have found a solution. Some theory you can find [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Hardware_video_acceleration) and [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Firefox#Hardware_video_acceleration). In short: Firefox understand only VA-API HW acceleration. VA-API do not support Nvidia proprietary drivers. So we need a driver, that pretend to be VA-API but have NVDEC under its hood. Driver is [here](https://github.com/elFarto/nvidia-vaapi-driver).

**3 important things:**

1. I was unable to make Firefox stable to see this new driver. So I had to install unstable branch [Firefox Nightly](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/channel/desktop/#nightly).
2. It did not work on default EGL backend so I had to add **NVD_BACKEND=direct** to `/etc/environment`
3. It's a bit tricky to make it understand VP9 codec that YouTube often use. So install that **libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-dev** before compiling or just install FF addon **h264ify** that will force YouTube to use good old h264 codec.

Comment: I do not understand the part of libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-dev. What am I supposed to be compiling? I hope not Firefox as it's managed by my package manager and I like to keep it that way. And compiling is impossible anyways because I seem to be cursed by always having compiler error whenever I try to compile whatever downloaded sources, and no amount of googling helps because no one else in the world ever has my compiler errors.