# high cpu usage by a firefox subprocess called RDD Process

Tags: firefox

Does anyone know how to fix this high cpu usage by a firefox subprocess called RDD Process ... or as a temporary band-aid How can I disable "RDD Process" until it gets fixed on firefox  ? as a loyal ff user since its "there be dragons" days I'd hate to stop using ff however new ff users will not put up with this ff bug

here is top showing this

```
$ top

top - 10:46:45 up  1:33,  1 user,  load average: 1.52, 1.12, 0.75
Tasks: 451 total,   1 running, 449 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
%Cpu(s):  7.1 us, 10.2 sy,  0.0 ni, 82.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :  63964.8 total,  48381.4 free,  10170.6 used,   5412.8 buff/cache
MiB Swap:  67584.0 total,  67584.0 free,      0.0 used.  52009.7 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                      
   9616 olaf      20   0  687632 124196  98824 S 167.6   0.2   8:06.11 RDD Process                                                                  
  11115 olaf      20   0 3478912   1.0g 142712 S  45.9   1.6   2:05.58 Isolated Web Co                                                              
   9154 olaf      20   0 5345052 918880 434104 S  37.8   1.4   9:23.10 firefox-trunk                                                                
   3318 olaf      20   0 7468292 375644 173560 S   8.1   0.6   4:51.18 gnome-shell                                                                  
   3828 root      20   0  394520  33684  27112 S   5.4   0.1   0:00.70 fwupd                                                                        
  19979 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   5.4   0.0   0:09.26 kworker/u32:0-i915                                                           
  20667 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   5.4   0.0   0:06.43 kworker/u32:4-i915                                                           
     65 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   2.7   0.0   0:00.78 ksoftirqd/8                                                                  
   3084 olaf       9 -11 2622692  31628  22540 S   2.7   0.0   0:25.00 pulseaudio                                                                   
   9014 olaf      20   0  751244  92592  66272 S   2.7   0.1   0:06.94 gnome-terminal-
```

This just started other day ... previously I have never seen RDD

```
firefox   118.0a1 (2023-08-19) (64-bit)


uname -m && uname -r && cat /etc/*release
x86_64
6.2.0-26-generic
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=22.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=jammy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS"
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
```

and yes it did not help by resetting my local settings by issuing

```
        rm -rf ~/.mozilla
        rm -rf ~/.cache/mozilla
```

this is on a beefy desktop and this RDD Process was consistently using high cpu forever ... it was not a temp short lived cpu spike ... however after repeatedly killing firefox and relaunching the RDD did reappear across several such cycles ... as I write RDD Process is gone yet this entire sequence of events has repeated itself across past week or so

coincidentally with above RDD issue, youtube now sometimes fails to play a video upon clicking the video yet same video plays OK on other browsers like Vivaldi

Below answer does not solve this high cpu issue ... How can I disable "RDD Process" until it gets fixed ?  I do not want a cpu core pegged all day as I continuously use firefox even when only viewing very well behaved sites like SO ... after killing ff all is OK until I try to watch a youtube video at which point cpu goes to 100% and stays pegged forever AND the youtube video fails to render

*UPDATE* hamburger menu -> Troubleshoot Mode -> Restart ... just to disable all addons afterwards the RDD issue goes away however I would never use ff without my addons so this is not a solution

Major fault of this RDD bug is that cpu usage increases each time I click on a youtube video in a different tab even though none of these videos plays ... the video just sits there not rendering any video after clicking on it AND this high cpu usage continues even after I click on a different tab say the tab for this SO question ... see new tab under this condition :

```
top - 08:04:00 up 36 min,  1 user,  load average: 2.40, 2.68, 1.68
Tasks: 420 total,   1 running, 413 sleeping,   0 stopped,   6 zombie
%Cpu(s):  4.6 us,  9.5 sy,  0.0 ni, 85.8 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.1 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :  63964.8 total,  49344.6 free,   6397.0 used,   8223.1 buff/cache
MiB Swap:  67584.0 total,  67584.0 free,      0.0 used.  56082.6 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                      
  85851 olaf      20   0  670148 122840  96472 S 162.5   0.2   4:09.69 RDD Process                                                                  
  26395 olaf      20   0 4256544 673516 298232 S  20.8   1.0   4:22.72 firefox-trunk                                                                
  26727 olaf      20   0 2909912 374900 134212 S  14.6   0.6   1:37.87 Isolated Web Co                                                              
  66057 olaf      20   0 3264688 688376 137424 S  13.2   1.1   1:41.47 Isolated Web Co                                                              
      9 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   4.9   0.0   0:18.76 kworker/u32:0-i915                                                           
    827 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   4.2   0.0   0:22.57 kworker/u32:11-i915                                                          
   3350 olaf      20   0 7202140 354256 163644 S   2.1   0.5   1:06.91 gnome-shell                                                                  
     15 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.7   0.0   0:01.31 rcu_preempt                                                                  
     41 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.7   0.0   0:01.79 ksoftirqd/4                                                                  
     54 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.7   0.0   0:03.61 kworker/6:0-events
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION

```
on firefix goto URL     about:config
and search for          media.rdd

then double click on    media.rdd-process.enabled
to give it a value of   false
```

for source see  https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=262227

Answer (score 5):

That is called [Remote Data Decoder (RDD)](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Sandbox/Process_model#Remote_Data_Decoder_.28RDD.29) … It ensures that media decoders for web content are run in their own isolated process … It’s part of FireFox's [Sandboxing Architecture](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Sandbox/Process_model) … Strict sandboxing is getting adopted by major web browsers including FireFox as a security standard to isolate web content involved processes from the rest of the system/user processes … Nowadays rich web content enabling processes have become much more demanding of system resources and much more needy for high privileges that they must be strictly sandboxed in order to unleash their full potential safely.

High load spikes for short periods as is reflected with your system's reported load average i.e. `load average: 1.52, 1.12, 0.75` are normal even if those spikes show an unexpected high number in e.g. `top` due to the nature of web content media rendering.

Please see related as well with more in depth discussion:

- [Firefox: "isolate+" process CPU usage 100%](https://askubuntu.com/q/1466241)
- [How do I use the user namespace sandbox?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1475711)